# How do I set a property of an Ember Component from another Component?

Tags: ember.js

So I created part of this app that has a modal-window component that is supposed to open when you set the property enabled to true..

application.hbs has this:

```
{{#modal-window enabled=true title="Manage Admins"}}
{{/modal-window}}
```

In modal-window.js I have an action closeModal that does `this.set('enabled',false)` and likewise to open it, you set it to true.

There is a nav menu on the bottom of the app which uses different components help-link, admin-link, etc. admin-link is also a component with its own hbs and js file. This is how the app was designed. At the bottom of index.hbs:

```
  <div class="configs-list-footer">
{{help-link}}
{{admin-link action='showModal'}}
<div class="logout-link">
  <a {{action 'invalidateSession'}} class="tv-icon">
    <svg width="18px" height="18px" viewBox="0 0 18 18" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><g transform="translate(1.000000, 1.000000)"><path d="M0.347826087,8 L10.7826087,8"></path><polyline id="Stroke-937" points="8 5.2173913 10.7826087 8 8 10.7826087"></polyline><path d="M1.03123478,4.83526957 C2.23471304,2.18831304 4.90253913,0.347617391 8.00027826,0.347617391 C12.2263652,0.347617391 15.6524522,3.77370435 15.6524522,7.9997913 C15.6524522,12.2258783 12.2263652,15.6519652 8.00027826,15.6519652 C4.88862609,15.6519652 2.21036522,13.7952696 1.01453913,11.1288348"></path></g></g></svg>
    <span>Logout</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

The action there calls an action in the admin-link.js file but there seems to be no way to tell modal-window to set enabled to true from OUTSIDE of itself which is a basic function of any program.

I cannot for the life of me after searching the Internet for hours figure out how to simply have the 'enabled' property of modal-window set to true when clicking on the admin-link component (which is basically an anchor tag)..

I have found out how to call an action from the Index route, but then just like with component to component I cannot figure out how to change the property of modal-window from the Index route.

Anytime anyone online asks how to do this they are met with "Components should be isolated and unaware of everything else" with no apparent way to do something so basic for a UI.

I'm using Ember 2.12.1

Answer (score 2):

I am aware this is an Ember question; but I highly suggest you to go over [Quick start documentation of React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html). There is quite good explanation about component oriented front-end development. One particular phrase exists in [Lifting state up section](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) is the following: "Often, several components need to reflect the same changing data. We recommend lifting the shared state up to their closest common ancestor."

This is the case with you now. The state of showing the modal dialog does not belong to `modal-window` itself because you need to toggle it from somewhere else. Hence you need to manage this state at the common ancestor; that is the `application.js` controller in your case I guess. Hence, actions should be bubbled up to `application` controller (I mean even the closing of the modal dialog should be performed by `application` controller within an action).

Regarding your question, AFAIK there is not a way you can set a property of a component from within another component. The technique I generally apply is lifting the state up to a common ancestor. Rarely, I prefer to create a `service` and define attributes and functions within the service to maintain application-wide state. Hence, if you prefer this second approach you can inject the service into both components and one component can display a state that belongs to the service whereas the other can modify it through functions within service.

You are right about components being isolated. However a component that solely works in isolation is useless; components should accept attributes from owners and should provide actions (events) to work upon. Do not forget to apply data down action up principle and it generally works good with lifting state up principle. This has been a long description; but I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is what mikej said below or mostly did it the code example he wrote. I understand both of these and yet neither solves my issue because I have no idea HOW TO MAKE IT WORK. application.js, index.js, app.js, xyz.js.. I have no clue what to put where because no one ever says it, everything is "put "it" in the controller" without saying what the bloody hell "it" is and WHICH controller and what file that is explicitly and where to put it in the file. I see examples where it's put outside of the Ember.whatever.extend, examples where it's put in the object, etc.

Comment: i will try to make you a very simple demo of your case at twiddle when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an answer to your exact question, but the approach we use for modals is to wrap the component in a conditional rather than making it a property of the component. e.g.

```
{{#if manageAdminsIsOpen}}
  {{#modal-window title="Manage Admins"}}
  {{/modal-window}}
{{/if}}
```

and then actions on the controller are used to toggle `manageAdminsIsOpen`.

I made an Ember Twiddle showing [an example](https://ember-twiddle.com/75d6ad9415a68f417caf4f3c04fbe741?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.admin-link.hbs).

Comment: I have a conditional on the modal-window itself but that is a good idea. Then I can manipulate that condition from the route itself as opposed from the component.Would still like to see the answer to my question just for future purposes. Our entire app was built in Ember by an outside contractor and I'm going to have to learn it well.

Comment: So I put this code in there but I'm not sure where to define manageAdminsIsOpen.. I assume I set it with this.set('manageAdminsIsOpen') from the index route's action but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I am super confused with this. I have application.hbs, application.js, index.js, index.hbs, and a ton of other files, and just like in the official ember docs I never have any clue which file to put code in. I just tried to put isManageAdmins in EVERY JS file both inside the Ember extend section as a property of the object there or just in the javascript outside that block and it doesn't work regardless of where I put it. Does just putting "manageAdminsIsOpen" in that if block define it? does it have to be defined explicitly somewhere?

Comment: Hi! I made an example of this and updated the answer with a link, although this might still leave you confused ;-) if you update your SO profile with an email address or Twitter I can recommend some tutorials you might find helpful.

Comment: The example makes perfect sense and is for the most part the way I have things set up, though my modal is way more complicated than that, and when I put all the stuff in exactly like in your example it says that

`Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...) is not a function
    at Class.manageClicked (admin-link.js:6)
    at Backburner.run (ember.debug.js:720)
    at Backburner.join (ember.debug.js:746)
    at Function.run.join (ember.debug.js:21556)
    at ember.debug.js:9478
    at Object.flaggedInstrument (ember.debug.js:17747)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (ember.debug.js:9477)`

Comment: Then when I look at the line it's this one `this.get('on-click')();`

Comment: Did you use `on-click` as the name the property on your `{{admin-link}}` or did you use something different? `this.get('on-click')` fetches the value of `on-click` from `{{admin-link on-click=(action "showModal")}}`. This will be a function thanks to the way the `action` helper [works in this context](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_action) and then the trailing `()` calls it. so `..is not a function` sounds like a different property name or a slight typo in the `{{admin-link}}`.

Comment: Ah. I had missed putting the `on-click` in `{{admin-link}}` .. I fixed it and got this error: `EmberError {description: undefined, fileName: undefined, lineNumber: undefined, message: "Assertion Failed: An action named 'showModal' was not found in (generated index controller)", name: "Error"…}`

Comment: Now I can see what's going on here.. In your example you have the `showModal/hideModal` in `application.js` and the `{{admin-link}}` in `application.hbs`.. In our app the nav menu is actually defined in the index route, index.hbs .. and I noticed I do have showModal in index.js under app/routes that opens it up with jQuery (the way I chose to go temporarily until I figured it out 'the ember way') and yet this error says that it's not found, however it's saying it's not found in the *generated* index controller, which leads me to believe it isn't looking at that index.js file. Dunno.

Comment: If your `{{admin-link}}` is in `templates/index.hbs` then you can create the corresponding controller `controllers/index.js` and put the `showModal/hideModal` actions in there. This file can be generated with `ember g controller index` or just grab the contents from my `controllers/application.js` example. The "generated" in the error message means that since there wasn't an index controller file found then Ember dynamically generated an (empty) controller object for you at runtime.

Comment: It still doesn't work and fiddling with it I've been unable to make it work. The manageAdminsIsOpen property is in application.js and I imagine that's the one that controls the modal window, the one in the new index.js controller does nothing, and looking at `this` in that controller, that object does not have a parentView property which leads to any parent so I can't access anything else.

So basically the outcome: Zero errors this time, the showModal action in the new controller actually DOES trigger, but it does not open the modal window.